# Set numeric only for text-field in ASP onKeyDown

Tags: asp.net, numeric, onkeydown

This solution works perfectly in all browsers and this is very easy use.

1. This is work without Numpad.

> **onkeydown = "return (!(event.keyCode>=65) && event.keyCode!=32);"**

2. This is work with Numpad.

> **onkeydown = "return (!((event.keyCode>=65 && event.keyCode <= 95) || event.keyCode >= 106) && event.keyCode!=32);"**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best way

```
<input type="number" name="txtNum" />
```

No script required.

Comment: Good. But I think this is best for HTML5. For the ASP.net I think that one practice is good. Thank you for your idea.

Comment: You should have learn't that aspx engine is built upon basic html, hence everything that is supported by html is also supported by aspx engine.